How to add onHover in searchField
I am new in flutter and have a question.
I have a SEARCHFIELD, and I want it to be possible to go over the list with the mouse to grab the value that I am currently standing on without actually selecting it.
Is there a function like onHover in searchField??
How to do that?.....
